# Projection Of fields not working in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
sample.getCollection()
      .find({},{"name":0,_id:0})
      .toArray(function(err1,res) 
        {
         if(err1)
            return console.log(err1);
         console.log(res);
        });
```

I have been trying to hide the fields in the find query of MongoDb in Node.js , but **Projection** part is not working as expected. Neither it is showing any error in the query. It is showing all the available fields in the all documents .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find({},{"name":0,_id:0})` is native mongodb syntax.

Try something like this -

```
sample.getCollection()
      .find({}).project({"name":0,_id:0})
      .toArray(function(err1,res) 
        {
         if(err1)
            return console.log(err1);
         console.log(res);
        });
```

Comment: Yes , Worked for me